# Python 2.7 - Need to replace "\xampp..." with another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7. I'm trying to replace a string with a new string. This is the code:

```
somestring = "C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH"
thestring = somestring
thenewstring = thestring.replace("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email\\BLAHBLAH", "something")
print thestring
print thenewstring
```

What I want to see printed:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH

something
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

**EDIT: Let's pretend that I have no access to do anything at all with the top line. It is set in stone. I'm reading in meta data from a Word document and looking for that exact string and then trying to replace it with a new string. My code's involvement starts on line 2. It is not a duplicate of that question because I am not working with a literal string.** I've read through quite a few question/answers on here and I'm understanding that "\x" is some kind of special thing that replace can't find for reasons I don't understand. I've tried several of the suggestions (like using "repr", or "decode") but I can't get any of them to work.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Add extra `'\'`s in the first line: `thestring = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email\\BLAHBLAH"`. (You have them in the second line, why not in the first?) It also looks like you replace the _whole_ original string with another string. Why not simply assign a new string to the new variable? `thenewstring = "something"`

Comment: That works but unfortunately, in the actual code, I don't have access to change what's inside "thestring". I'm reading in meta data from a Word Document and finding that exact string (which I can't change) and then replacing it with something else.

Comment: So, you do _not_ actually have the assignment on the first line of your example? Then please remove it (because it is causing the error) and simply print the value of `thestring`.

Comment: Well, I do have the assignment, it just looks like this instead "contents = file.read().replace(search, replace)". I just changed it to make it clearer for the question. file.read() would contain "C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH".

Comment: You have an error in one of the functions that you call. Until you find out, in which, do not lump them together. What do you see if you `print` the result of `fd.read())` before you replace anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not feasible for me to get. It's part of a large application that runs behind the scenes inside a docker container. I've traced it back to what I think is the problem. Is there no solution to what I asked in the original question assuming I can't change anything between the double quotes in thestring?

Answer (score -1):

If you have an error using

```
thestring = "C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH"
```

you should use this:

```
thestring = r"C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH"
```

the final code that you want:

```
thestring = r"C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH"
thenewstring = thestring.replace("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\email\\BLAHBLAH", "something")
print thestring
print thenewstring
```

the output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH
something
```

Please, note the "r" before the string.
If you want more information about this: [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Comment: This worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @JustaSecUser: if this works, then why did you tell DYZ in the comments that you weren't working with a string literal?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I jumped the gun saying this works. It *does* work for the example I provided but what if "C:\xampp\htdocs\email\BLAHBLAH" were in a variable? How would I use the "r" next to a variable? thestring = [r]file.read()

Comment: if you want to use it with a variable:
print my_variable.encode('string-escape')